# Where's the documentation for running Angular IDE in Eclipse

Tags: angular, eclipse

I've just installed Angular IDE for Eclipse from here but I'm not seeing documentation for how to run an existing Angular project in Eclipse using Angular IDE.  For example, how do I start an instance of 'ng serve' in Eclipse, deploy an application to the instance, and set break points and step through the code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The house-like link under the Install button takes you to https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/ . I'm not sure where the doc is there, though.

Answer (score 1):

John, the doc is here: https://www.genuitec.com/products/angular-ide/learning-center/ it's reachable from the Learning center menu item on our Angular IDE website as pointed out by nitind earlier. More specific topics [here](https://www.genuitec.com/docs/web-apps/modern-web/). If you need further assistance, you can also reach out to us using the Live Chat feature within the product.

I noticed you had another post about WWD - if you're using Angular IDE, you don't need to use WWD, though there's typically no harm in having it installed as well.